# Lua extension in vscode suddenly adding stuff to my code

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting

I am using the sumneko extension for lua in vscode.

I was editing the settings.json to try to stop autocomplete in comments, but somewhere in the process, I messed something up, and now in my code I am seeing extra words, such as:

`require 'utils'`   
becomes:
`require modname:'utils'`

I'm also seeing :table, :integer, :string, etc, so it looks like the highlighter is analyzing the status of function arguments, and adding that as text.  I'd love if it changed the color, rather than adding the text, but I've yet to find any setting that looks like it would do that.

The new characters do not copy, so are display only, I suppose.  They seem like useful information, and I wonder if they are supposed to be showing up as highlighting instead?? That would be nice!  But still they are very confusing to see in my code...  I am using the default dark theme.

Can someone tell me what setting I inadvertently turned on?  Also, I am still getting auto-complete in comments, despite turning it off.  I'm also seeing word completion, although the delay seems to work.  I don't know if the issues are related.  Can you see anything wrong in my settings file?  It is not showing any syntax errors.

Here is the settings.json file:

```
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
    "editor.quickSuggestions": { "other": false, "comments": false, "strings": false },
    "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 1000,
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,

    "Lua.workspace.library": {


    },
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "diffEditor.renderSideBySide": true,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "Lua.awakened.cat": false,
    "Lua.completion.callSnippet": "Both",

    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "workbench.enableExperiments": false,
    "workbench.sash.size": 6,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "Lua.hover.viewNumber": false,
    "Lua.hover.viewString": false,
    "Lua.intelliSense.searchDepth": 10,

    "Lua.completion.workspaceWord": false,
    "Lua.diagnostics.workspaceDelay": 1000,
    "Lua.diagnostics.workspaceRate": 70,
    "Lua.hover.previewFields": 20,
}
```

and here is the workspace settings.json file, in case that matters:

```
{
    "Lua.diagnostics.globals": [
        "gfx",
        "reaper",
        "GetRGB",
        "RandomColor",
        "MButtonPanel"
    ],
    "Lua.diagnostics.disable": [
        "unused-function",
        "undefined-global",
    ]
}
```

Comment: Actually, the delay in autocomplete is not working either...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I discovered the developer's github site had a q&a forum, and he answered the question about the display-only items.  It was a setting, with a non-obvious (to me!) name:

hint:param type

that mysteriously got turned on...

Just in case someone else comes here looking.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make the assumption that those contextual "display only" items are a feature and you won't be able to change that.

However, worst case you can always go into the C:\Users\YOU\.vscode\extensions\TheLuaExtension\ folder and edit the package.json file to read like you have above...

`"editor.quickSuggestions": { "other": false, "comments": false, "strings": false },`

My point is, the information is coming from somewhere, if it is ignoring your personal settings, then change the definition it is using.

Comment: I'll try that... did not know about package.json